# Fetching results from query and separating based on values - why won't > < = symbols work correctly?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm not exactly sure how to title this, so if someone knows a better title I would greatly appreciate it.

So, basically I am fetching two timestamps and calculating the difference in minutes from an oracle database and parsing them to my PHP doc, where I am counting them based on the `if` loop, below.

Everything seems to work fine, except the only values actually entering the loop are those that are `< 50`, `50 > < 100`, and `100 > < 150`. Why is this?

SQL:

```
select a.num_1 as Job_ID, a.tycod as Job_Type,
    to_char(to_date(substr(nvl(a.off_dts,a.ad_ts),1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as off_dts,
    to_char(to_date(substr(min(u.cdts),1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as disp_dts,
            (to_char(( to_date(substr(min(u.cdts),1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') - to_date(substr(nvl(a.off_dts,a.ad_ts),1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') )) * 24 * 60) as DIFF
from aeven a,un_hi u
where to_date(substr(AD_TS,1,14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') > to_date('01/01/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
    and a.curent = 'T'
    and a.dgroup not like '%99'
    and a.dgroup not like '%98'
    and a.event_status <> 'C'
    and a.tycod = 'TRWIRE'
    and not exists (SELECT P_EID FROM XREF X WHERE A.EID = X.S_EID AND X_TYPE = 'X')
    and a.eid = u.eid
    and u.unid not like 'FSA%'
    and u.unit_status in ('DA','DP')
    group by a.num_1,a.tycod, u.cdts, a.ad_ts, a.off_dts,
    to_char(to_date(substr(nvl(a.off_dts,a.ad_ts),1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Example Results:

```
JOB_ID          JOB_TYPE      OFF_DTS             DISP_DTS         DIFF
T14020300128    TRWIRE  02/03/2014 19:34:44 02/04/2014 12:06:45 992.01666
W14040700061    TRWIRE  04/07/2014 10:27:51 04/07/2014 10:29:33 1.
T14041300447    TRWIRE  04/13/2014 15:33:57 04/13/2014 15:36:00 2.049999
W14040900078    TRWIRE  04/09/2014 13:31:24 04/10/2014 08:13:55 1122.5166666
N14041300268    TRWIRE  04/13/2014 09:57:22 04/13/2014 10:24:45 27.383333333
N14041300268    TRWIRE  04/13/2014 09:57:22 04/13/2014 10:24:49 27.45
N14041201144    TRWIRE  04/12/2014 21:59:28 04/13/2014 09:01:11 661.717
N14041201144    TRWIRE  04/12/2014 21:59:28 04/13/2014 11:29:28 810
T14041300274    TRWIRE  04/13/2014 10:15:02 04/13/2014 10:31:33 16.5166666
T14041401323    TRWIRE  04/14/2014 16:35:22 04/14/2014 16:57:00 21.633333
N14041300434    TRWIRE  04/13/2014 13:26:28 04/13/2014 13:31:57 5.483333333
N14041400108    TRWIRE  04/14/2014 07:09:56 04/14/2014 07:27:46 17.8333333
N14041400108    TRWIRE  04/14/2014 07:09:56 04/14/2014 07:27:48 17.8666666
N14041600107    TRWIRE  04/16/2014 09:37:08 04/16/2014 09:54:46 17.63333333
N14041600158    TRWIRE  04/16/2014 10:53:57 04/16/2014 11:02:55 8.9666666
T14041401308    TRWIRE  04/14/2014 16:17:42 04/14/2014 16:23:15 5.5500000
T14041401308    TRWIRE  04/14/2014 16:17:42 04/14/2014 16:25:50 8.13333
```

If Loop:

```
if(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) < 50) {
    $LT50 = $LT50 + 1;
} elseif(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 50 && round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) < 100) {
    $GT50_LT100 = $GT50_LT100 + 1;
} elseif(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 100 && round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) < 150) {
    $GT100_LT150 = $GT100_LT150 + 1;
} elseif(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 150 && round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 200) {
    $GT150_LT200 = $GT150_LT200 + 1;
} elseif(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 200 && round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) < 250) {
    $GT200_LT250 = $GT200_LT250 + 1;
} elseif(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 300 && round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) < 350) { 
    $GT300_LT350 = $GT300_LT350 + 1;
} elseif(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 350 && round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) < 400) {
    $GT350_LT400 = $GT350_LT400 + 1;
} elseif(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 400 && round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) < 450) {
    $GT400_LT450 = $GT400_LT450 + 1;
} elseif(round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0) > 450) {
    $GT450 = $GT_450 + 1; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to save `round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0)` in a variable. It's not good always doing the same. What you forgot (or your logical error) is, that if a value is exact a value where you're requiring to be higher (100 for example) it does nothing.

```
$diff = round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"), 0);
if($diff < 50) {
    $LT50 = $LT50 + 1;
} elseif($diff >= 50 && $diff < 100) {
    $GT50_LT100 = $GT50_LT100 + 1;
} elseif($diff >= 100 && $diff < 150) {
    $GT100_LT150 = $GT100_LT150 + 1;
} elseif($diff >= 150 && $diff < 200) {
    $GT150_LT200 = $GT150_LT200 + 1;
} elseif($diff >= 200 && $diff < 250) {
    $GT200_LT250 = $GT200_LT250 + 1;
} elseif($diff >= 300 && $diff < 350) { 
    $GT300_LT350 = $GT300_LT350 + 1;
} elseif($diff >= 350 && $diff < 400) {
    $GT350_LT400 = $GT350_LT400 + 1;
} elseif($diff >= 400 && $diff < 450) {
    $GT400_LT450 = $GT400_LT450 + 1;
} elseif($diff >= 450) {
    $GT450 = $GT_450 + 1;
}
```

Comment: Up'd for the assistance with the `round(OCIResult($stmt, "DIFF"),0)`, however this does not help my current situation :/ just cleans the code up

Comment: Look at the code again. I'm sure you'll find the big difference. :)

Comment: After using your code, I definitely am much closer. However, it still does not work for `$diff >= 450`. Everything else seems right, though. Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, you can pretty much just use `} else {` instead of `} elseif($diff >= 450) {`, since it's practically the same.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Look at the second to last line `$GT450 = $GT_450 + 1;`. If you change it to `$GT450 = $GT450 + 1;` than life is good! Thanks :)